# Load contents of page depending on linked selected

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing an admin dashboard in PHP at the moment.
To simplify things, as far as I think it simplifies, the page I structured has the typical areas Header, Aside with menu and MainContent page. The main content page should change when I click a different page in the aside menu.

So I created the page index.php which will hold the whole framework of the page.

```
<?php include('../includes/overall/overallHeader.php'); ?>

<section class="content-header">
    <h1>Einsatzliste</h1>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pageIncidents').click(function(){
        $('#mainContent').load('incidents.php');
    });
</script>

<section class="content">
    <div id="mainContent">

    </div>
</section>

<?php include('../includes/overall/overallFooter.php'); ?>
```

Within this I created the section content, and gave the div inside the id mainContent. My idea was to load different subpages into this div, when I click a menu item in the aside menu:

**aside menu**

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
            <li><a href=""><div id="pageIncidents">Einsatzliste</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Testseite 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

There I put the link inside a div with a unique ID which I want to use in jQuery to load the specific contents.

**jQuery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pageIncidents').click(function(){
        $('#mainContent').load('incidents.php');
    });
</script>
```

The script is supposed to load the page incidents.php into the div mainContent in the index.php page.

It totally does not work... Do you have a hint where to look for? I think the logic seems right I guess. Could it be a problem, that the id "pageIncidents" is not directly visible in the code but included by the php include overallHeader at the top of the page?

Comment: The content is briefly appearing and then disappearing

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors and inspected the document structure via your browser developer tools after clicking the link?

Comment: Yep. The content is there for a second roughly and then disappearing from the page. After that I inspected the page and the div container is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it with ajax and make up the ajax response in html (string), onclick start ajax request.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-asset", function() {
   var link = $(this).attr('[data-page]');
   $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url:'http://www.example.com/index.php',
   dataType: "json",
   data: { 
       action: 'incidents',
       data: { 'incidents': 'incidents' }
  },
 success:function(data) {
    $('#mainContent').html("[your data]");
}
});
});
```